# Change Fullcalendar width

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar plugin and I've been looking how to change the width of the calendar but I don't know how to do it. Fullcalendar is 100% width by default, but I would like to be 80%. I've edited the fc.table width in the css stylesheet but the last column stays deformed. Maybe someone has been there, so if you could help me I would thank you a lot.

Answer (score 8):

You can apply css stles to the div containing the calendar

```
<div id='calendar' style="width: 80%; display: inline-block;"></div>
```

Comment: Oh that's good news, don't forget to mark my post as an answer. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You should set **width** as style and don't forget to render it.

e.g

```
loadInitialData() {
      const calendarApi = this.$refs.mcalendar.getApi();

      this.columns.forEach((column) => {
        calendarApi.addResource(column);
      });

      const calendarWidth = this.columns.length * 210;
      $('.multi-calendar .fc-timegrid').css('width', calendarWidth);

      this.events.forEach((event) => {
        calendarApi.addEvent(event);
      });

      calendarApi.render();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

give `height` as an option, but `width` as element's style. example:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/fullcalendar@5.1.0/main.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/fullcalendar@5.1.0/main.min.css" />
<div id="calendar" style="width: 700px;"></div>
<style>
</style>
<script>
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      height: 550,
  });
  calendar.render();
</script>
```